# Shadowsocks causing ERR_SSL_BAD_RECORD_MAC_ALERT on Windows 10

Tags: networking, windows-10, proxy, socks-proxy

I am a regular Shadowsocks user. Recently when I perform certain actions, all my browsers stop to display the page for me, and the action is not done. For example, while I can browse and comment on posts on Stack Exchange, I cannot ask new questions or submit new answers, unless I turn off Shadowsocks. Some authorization also fails, for example I can't log in to GitHub, and even after logging in, I cannot use GitHub OAuth to authorize other services, but I can browse code as normal. I also cannot open new issues or PRs, or add comments or upload images.

It seems like many "write" actions gets this error while "read" don't.

In Google Chrome I frequently see `ERR_SSL_BAD_RECORD_MAC_ALERT` on errored pages and I think this is the exact error across all problems I'm having.

I Googled that keyword and found many solutions, and I tried some of them, but to no avail.

- I set the MTU of my current network adapter to 1400 (was 1500) with `netsh interface ipv4 set ......` and rebooted
- I unchecked "TLS 1.0" and "TLS 1.1" in IE settings, leaving only "SSL 3.0" and "TLS 1.2" checked (there's no option for "SSL 2.0")
- Cleared SSL cache
- Hyper-V is not active on my PC - I am a VMware user
- I have no bridged network.

Another thing is that my network entry is my mobile hotspot, while I have perfectly no issues if I do these things on my phone, even if it's connected to the same server with Shadowsocks for Android.

Quitting Shadowsocks is not an option for a mainland China user, nor is re-installing Windows fresh (don't have time for now). How can I solve this problem?

Comment: FYI: SSL3 was broken 4 years ago (POODLE) and if you managed make an SSL3 connection it would be badly insecure, but all properly run servers in the world (sadly not nearly all) since at least 2-3 years ago ignore any attempt to negotiate it. TLS1.1 is still safe (though 1.2 is _better_) and in practice most of the time 1.0 is safe enough although standards like PCI DSS prohibit it. But that doesn't help with your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few hours of re-installing Windows and various stuff, I finally found out that this is a driver issue.

TL;DR If you are a MSI laptop user and encounter this issue, please update your Killer network adapter driver. You can find latest drivers [here](https://www.killernetworking.com/killersupport/driver-downloads).

---

I was looking into another issue when I accidentally found the solution.

I re-installed Windows fresh a few days ago, installed a few "basic software" like Office and WinRAR, as well as all the drivers downloaded from MSI's official website. I soon noticed that it was ridiculous for a freshly-installed Windows 10 to eat up 5.5 GB of RAM at boot, but no suspicious program was running.

Later I spared some time for experiments. I set aside a partition and installed Windows fresh again, carefully watching RAM usage when installing every single piece of software. It didn't took me long to spot that during the "install driver" phase in the installation of Killer Network Suite, the RAM usage suddenly went from 1.6 GB to 3.4 GB.

I then [searched](https://www.google.com/search?q=killer+driver+too+much+ram) for *killer driver too much ram* and found [this thread](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/msi-gt73vr-very-high-ram-usage-for-no-reason-on-windows-10.811914/). It said disabling "Windows Network Data Usage Monitor Driver" would help, but it was already disabled on my laptop. So I just went on and updated my driver, enjoying the fix for the memory leak.

Later I found [this page](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/591084) which mentions some network error related to Killer drivers. I then verified that my SSL error was no longer there, so I considered that it was fixed by the driver update.